# How to generate new private/public keys in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I need to create a pair (private/public) keys with Node.JS I need it because I'm developing a simple intranet messaging and I would like to share public keys

and only the ones that have the respective private key could read the data. Maybe I could use SSL directly but I need something custom for other things. Is it possible with crypto module ?
I mean something like: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a pair private/public keys using Node.js crypto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520973/how-to-create-a-pair-private-public-keys-using-node-js-crypto)