# TypeError: generateKeyPair is not a function when trying to use a function in the node.js crypto module

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the node.js module crypto to generate key pairs, but for some reason I cannot seem to use the `generateKeyPair` function.

I made sure crypto was installed and up to date, but nothing changed. Both the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback) and multiple [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52775583) show exactly the code I used, but don't work.

The code I used is this:

```js
const { generateKeyPair } = require('crypto');
generateKeyPair('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs8',
        format: 'pem',
        cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
        passphrase: 'top secret'
    }
}, (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was on the wrong node version, updating to 11.x fixed it

Comment: I am having the same issue but I'm on version 11.3.0 of node